# Universal Analog Input

Tags: mosfet

I am implementing this circuit but want to make it automated to avoid the use of jumper headers. I have replaced all the headers with P-FETs.

Is this the best solution?

[image: Universal Analog Input]

Comment: Why PFETs? I would use N-channel MOSFETs, With P-channel FETs you would need a negative voltage to switch them on. A Chip with analog switches or FET-based opto isolators might be easier to control. Even simpler if switching does not happen very often: a relay. Also: define "best solution", for some best solution is what is most reliable or most simple or simply the cheapest solution. There is no single "best solution".

Comment: Thank you for me the best solution is the simplest, cheapest and uses little board space this is why i am looking at a FET-based system.

Comment: What do you mean by "automated"?  What would control the FET switches?  Won't J11 have to be closed for the 20 mA loop option?

Comment: @AnalogKid the FETs will be switched through an IO expander controlled by the MCU, J11 does not need to be closed since R11 will only be adding impedance to the signal.

Comment: I'd place an EMI/RFI filter into pin 12, perhaps 1Kohm and 1UF, thus 160Hz LPF. And use a Ground Plane under the entire set of components, to which the 1uF is soldered.

Comment: If J11 is open, then the 1 V peak current loop signal will be attenuated to 0.1 V into the opamp.

Answer (score 1):

For this low-accuracy circuit, I suggest two n-channel logic-level MOSFETs, one between R14 and ground and one between R12 and ground. The first one needs low Rds(on), the second needs reasonable Rds(on) in relation to R12 (a few ohms is okay) and low leakage so not too much voltage is dropped across R11 when open.

I would suggest adding resistance before the zener to limit the current and adding a resistor (perhaps 100K) from input to ground so that the input is not floating with both MOSFETs off (which would drive the outputs high, causing the LM324 to try to dissipate ~2W for 4 channels used, and each zener over 200mW. The LM324 datasheet says:

> At values of supply voltage in excess of 15 V,
>   continuous short-circuits can exceed the power dissipation ratings and cause eventual destruction. Destructive dissipation can result
>   from simultaneous shorts on all amplifiers.

So even a single channel shorted is too many with your 18V supply.

Comment: @A.Lynn: Note that 24 V is common in industry for 0 - 20 mA sensors. You need to consider what happens if the current mode sensor is turned off and a 0 - 20 mA sensor is connected. It may pass > 18 V into your amplifier.

Comment: @Transistor The bipolar LM324 is okay with up to 32V in (not limited to the supply voltage). And there's 27K in series.

Comment: Good. I hadn't checked.

Comment: @Transistor You should leave your comment there, it's a good thing to check such things (becomes second nature after a while), for example the original design (not my mod of it) will be destroyed if J11 is closed and a substantial negative voltage is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your immunity requirements for ESD and EMI.

The ESD protection with FETs for some level of voltage protection equal to the capacitance of your cable of ~ 100 pF/m and not just the HBM of 100pF std test.

Then you can use 2 bit binary or 3 control lines to activate CMOS (2) and/or FET switches.

For EMI common mode noise, you need to define the noise spectrum and rejection ratio or CMRR.  This may be handled by some Op Amps or INstrument Amps (INA) and may require a CM choke and pi filter caps.

- If you cannot design and verify by testing for the above then  a safer approach is to use reed relays with a balanced protected INA and a SMD CM choke with caps.

> Is this the best solution?

NO, your solution has no specs for accuracy or immunity and **until then is unanswerable.**